# Errno 98 - La dirección ya está en uso

Tags: python, socket

Tengo un problema con mi código en Python. El error viene de algo bastante sencillo, de los sockets. Tengo un server y un cliente, pero cada vez que cierro el server e intento volver a ejecutarlo me salta el `[Errno 98] Adress already in use` lo cual es bastante molesto, pues si por algun casual se cierra de forma repentina, la única forma de volver a iniciarlo es cambiar el puerto tanto del server como del cliente. Existe la posibilidad de que cuando se cierre el server, quede libre el puerto que estaba ocupando para poder usarlo otra vez? Adjunto código:

```py
import socket 
s =socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("IP",puerto))
s.listen(10)

while True: 
   (sc,addr) = s.accept()
   while True:
   repro() #Funcion encargada de enviar/recibir info 
   break
sc.close()
```

Comment: el error es que puerto que abriste se encuentra ya en uso , intenta cambiar el puerto

Comment: Claro, de ahi viene el problema. Por ejemplo, yo ejecuto el server en el puerto 2020 y luego lo cierro. Cuando intento volver a abrirlo en el puerto 2020, que en teoria está libre, pues me ha dejado abrirlo la primera vez, me salta el error 98. Lo que me gustaria saber es si es posible que esto no ocurra para poder ejecutar el server todo el rato sobre el mismo puerto

Comment: es mas un error en tu programa, al hacer Ctrl-C no controlas el evento y no matas el proceso

Answer (score 0):

Tu código: a) tiene problemas de alineamiento y b) nunca cierra el socket del servidor.

Veamos:

```
while True: 
    (sc,addr) = s.accept()
```

Cliente conectado e inicio de la conversación

```
  while True:
       repro() # Función encargada de enviar/recibir info 
   break

sc.close()
```

En este punto el proceso finalizó. La ultima línea cerró un socket utilizado en alguna conexión cliente. Toma nota que te dará error si ya no es válido. Fin del programa. El socket del servidor quedo abierto. :<

Para solucionarlo basta con mover mas a la derecha una linea y agregar otra:

```
while True: 
    (sc,addr) = s.accept()
    while True:
        repro() \# Funcion encargada de enviar/recibir info  
        break
    sc.close() 
s.close()
```